# IPython Notebook WebSocket connection failed

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

With Chrome/Firefox and IPython 1.1 under Windows 7 64bit I've got the error "WebSocket connection failed" on opening an existing IPython notebook if using automatic proxy configuration (with authentication) though the configuration file contains exception for localhost.

I poked a little bit around in Chrome (30) and found in the Javascript console (F12):

```
Kernel started:  aec48410-068f-424f-8fc1-8fd229409e70 kernel.js:110
Starting WebSockets: ws://127.0.0.1:8888/kernels/aec48410-068f-424f-8fc1-8fd229409e70 kernel.js:143
WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8888/kernels/aec48410-068f-424f-8fc1-8fd229409e70/iopub' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8888/kernels/aec48410-068f-424f-8fc1-8fd229409e70/stdin' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
WebSocket connection failed:  ws://127.0.0.1:8888/kernels/aec48410-068f-424f-8fc1-8fd229409e70
```

Obviously the websocket server has been started and it is the right adress (same as output of ipython-notebook)

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Could there be a firewall or something? We've heard about problems with Sophos Antivirus especially.

Comment: and also eset by the way!

Answer (score 2):

It is about proxy configuration: We have a proxy that needs authentication and it is normally automatically configured by a central configuration file.

In this file there is an exception for localhost but for some reason this does not work.

Manually configuring the proxy with authentication and adding localhost as an exception did the job. And that was the difference between Firefox and Chrome - I forgot that I configured them differently.

Answer (score 2):

happened same with me. When I installed tensorflowjs, it downgraded my prompt-toolkit version to 1.0.14. To solve this issue just upgrade prompt-toolkit version to 3.0.5 by running the following code in your command prompt:

```
 pip install prompt-toolkit==3.0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into websocket closed/connection issues and `zmq message arrived on closed channel` when running jupyter notebook and jupyter lab. The issue was caused by running the xpython kernel. When I switched back to python3, all was good.